# Относятся ли повторитель и концентратор к устройствам коммутации компьютерной сети?

Tags: сеть

Относятся ли повторитель и концентратор к устройствам коммутации компьютерной сети? Мост и коммутатор подходят, а вот с этими устройствами (повторитель и концентратор) немного запутался

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всегда надо начинать с определений. Обычно их штук сто различных и не факт, что случайно выбранное понравится преподавателю, например.
Но если взять определение из Википедии, то:

"Коммута́ция в компьютерной сети — процесс соединения абонентов такой сети через транзитные узлы".

И повторитель и концентратор являются транзитными узлами? Да.
А соединение идет через них? Тоже зависит от определения, но в общем случае - да.
**Тогда и повторитель и концентратор относятся к устройствам коммутации.**

Но как только в определении коммутации появится хоть что-то про логику коммутации, то они перестанут относиться к таким устройствам, так как логикой в них особо не пахнет:-)